# Text and Image together in a Flutter Card

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I want to add an image and a text together in a card but I'm not able to do it. I think a row would be used here but not able to implement it. I'm new to flutter and app development so having some troubles. Any help is really appreciated. Also the cards are in GridView(not in ListView).

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_webview_plugin/flutter_webview_plugin.dart';
import 'lists.dart';

void main() {
runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   return MaterialApp(
  title: 'Just Another App',
  home: Home(),
  routes: {
    "/webview": (_) => WebviewScaffold(
          withJavascript: true,
          withLocalStorage: true,
          url: 'https://www.google.com/',
          appBar: AppBar(
            title: Text('Browser'),
          ),
        ),
  },
  theme: ThemeData(primaryColor: Colors.black),
);
}
}

class Home extends StatefulWidget {
@override
_HomeState createState() => _HomeState();
}

class _HomeState extends State<Home> {
  final webView = FlutterWebviewPlugin();

  @override
  void initState() {
   super.initState();
   webView.close();
 } 
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var gridView = GridView.builder(
        itemCount: 15,
        gridDelegate:
            SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(crossAxisCount: 3),
        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
          return InkWell(
            child: Card(
              elevation: 10,
              child: Padding(
               padding: const EdgeInsets.all(35),
               child: Container(
                 // child: SizedBox(child: Text('yashjha'),),
                 // child: Image.asset('lib/images/${images[index]}'),
                 decoration: BoxDecoration(
                   image: DecorationImage(
                     image: AssetImage('lib/images/${images[index]}'),
                     fit: BoxFit.fitWidth,
                      alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
                   ),
                 ),
               ),
             ),
            ),
            onTap: () {
              setState(() {
                Navigator.of(context).pushNamed('/webview');
              });
            },
          );
        });

return Scaffold(
  appBar: AppBar(
    title: Text('Just Another App'),
  ),
  body: Container(
    child: gridView,
    padding: EdgeInsets.all(12),
  ),
);
  }
[GridViewApp Screenshot][1]}
```

This is a variable which I'm using in the "body" of Scaffold.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to place an Image and a text side by side, Wrap Text and Image in Row widget like:

```
child: Row(
     children: <Widget>[
         DecorationImage(...),
         Text(...),
     ],
)
```

You can also set `mainAxisAlignment` and `crossAxisAlignment` to make sure that your widgets are placed correctly

Answer (score 0):

Just wrap your Container widget into a Row Widget and add a Text widget just before the Container widget like bellow.

```
Row(
          children: <Widget>[
            Text("add text here"),
            Container(
              // child: SizedBox(child: Text('yashjha'),),
              // child: Image.asset('lib/images/${images[index]}'),
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                image: DecorationImage(
                  image: AssetImage('lib/images/${images[index]}'),
                  fit: BoxFit.fitWidth,
                  alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
```